# Eclipse pop-up javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, javadoc

Is there a way for Eclipse that will pop-up the javadoc related to the code when I press, say, Ctrl + Shift + Space, as NetBeans does ? I don't like it to open attached javadoc in external or internal web browser.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use F2 shortcut to show tooltip/javadoc description for the element at the cursor.

Comment: Is there any way to explicitly show Javadoc in case the tooltip is overridden (e.g. via Checkstyle warning)?

Comment: @Daddy32 good one, looks like in this case F2 displays the warning details. There seem to be no way to override this, at least not obvious way. You can always use 'javadoc' view. There is a shortcut (alt + shift + q, j) to make it visible.

Answer (score 1):

It happens in eclipse when your mouse is over the interesting element. 
Additionally you can open javadoc view, so the javadoc will appear into this view. It is even more convenient especially if the description is long and cannot be viewed without scrolling.

Comment: Is not there any way to do the same by keyboard press ? In NetBeans, Ctrl + Shift + Space just pop-ups the javadoc without having to hover on code..