# Eclipse - @Deprecated warning hides java docs pop up

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint, deprecation-warning

In Eclipse Neon, when adding `@Deprecated` to method for example,

The Sonar S1133 warning of removing the deprecated method is blocking seeing the java docs of the method (when hovering over)

It prevents following `@deprecated` links.

Is there a way around it expect ignoring this specific warning? I just don't want it to block the java docs pop up

I saw that you can use [F2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047291/eclipse-pop-up-javadoc) to open pop up, but it's also show sonar warning instead.

Is it eclipse issue of pop up or sonar plugin issue that can be opened?

**EDIT**

The only solution I found is to deactivate this specific sonar warning

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for this same issue, I came upon this unreplied question. Digging some more, I've found a workaround. I'm using Eclipse Simrel 06-19.

Just check (or configure as you like) your hover preferences in Window->Preferences. Select in the tree Java->Editor->Hovers

This is my current (also the default) configuration:
[image: Java editor hover preferences]

On your specific case (as happened to me) you could just press Ctrl+Shift while hovering to display javadoc instead of the warning description (or just Shift to see the source).

Samples with the above config:

With no key held:
[image]

With Ctrl + Shift:
[image]

With Shift:
[image]
Hope this helps (although a bit late!)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have Eclipse Neon and it doesn't work (same configuration), can you add screenshots on what work for you? maybe I just need to upgrade